# Inconsistency in Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, multithreading, foreach, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am using Parallel.foreach for more than 500 iterations.

My loop is something like:

```
Parallel.ForEach(indexes, (index) =>
 {

 //parentCreation with index object
 parent=create(index);

//call of function to create children
createChildrenOfType1(parent);
createChildrenOfType2(parent);
 });
```

I am facing inconsistent output. Parents are created correctly but child creation is inconsistent.
Sometimes no child is created, sometimes only few are created and so on.
Child creation method again has for loop to create 100s of children.

How can I make my child creation consistent while using the parallel foreach for parent creation.

Comment: You're going to have to show your implementation of those create methods, I think.

Comment: Thread unsafe objects are thread unsafe

Comment: If you've ever played GTA and had too much to drink playing darts - that's what the world feels like when using unsafe objects in multi-threaded environments. It's just not normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue i see here is that you are modifying variables that are not declared inside the Parallel.ForEach code block, in which case you should lock them.

```
Parallel.ForEach(indexes, (index) =>
 {

 //parentCreation with index object
lock (lockerObject)
{
     parent=create(index);

    //call of function to create children
    createChildrenOfType1(parent);
    createChildrenOfType2(parent);
}
 });
```

By using lock, it ensures the threads sync properly.

Comment: Thanks all . Yes some of the variables were initialized out of the parallel for loop which was the reason for inconsistency.

Comment: I had similar issue and that fixed it. Not sure if it is the "best" way but it is easy and works. I upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `Parent` object has a `List<Child> Children` and your `createChildrenOfTypeX` functions are adding a new child to the Parent.Children list, and those `createChildrenOfTypeX` are also running a Parallel set of code then the List implementation must be thread safe; the standard System.Collections.Generic implementation is not thread safe.

Additionally if you have an external collection of `Parent` that you are adding the newly instantiated parents to, this also has to be thread safe, otherwise you could lose your parent instances as well.